# How to make cmd fullscreen

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-line-interface

How do I make command line run in fullscreen by default?
I changed the layout and increased the width and height of the cmd, but it doesnt open up to a perfect fullscreen.

Comment: Does Alt+Enter work ?

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/285984/how-do-i-full-screen-my-cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut with the following content:

> `PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Process cmd -WindowStyle Maximized"`